# Is it possible to upgrade the AMD E-300 APU on a laptop?

Tags: cpu, sockets

I read that this processor is BGA. That would mean that it is soldered to the motherboard? Can an average laptop technician replace it?

This processor is very slow, it scores only 600 on the Passmark CPU Benchmark.

Comment: Not all, but most BGA chips are soldered to the laptop. If their are then your average laptop technician can not replace them. A specialised electronics place might, but is likely to ask a relative high price compared the price of the motherboard+CPU/APU. (Assumption: An E-300 belongs to low power using netbooks, which are in the lower price classes)

Comment: In Brazil I believe you could find a mobile phone repair shop which would swap the bga chips for a small price.

Comment: the bios would also need to support the processor. Thats a pretty important thing you'd need to worry about

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Good point. If you really want a faster CPU, you're probably best off buying a new laptop with the specs you want, rather than upgrading to another processor in the same family which won't be much faster. A nice SNB Celeron system would be a bunch faster.

Comment: The point I was making in my answer which moderators converted into the comment above, is that it is very much doable by a qualified person. But Jader has much better chances of being helped in a mobile phone repair shop than in computer repair shop. So still "No" to the "can an average laptop tech do it?" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, BGA is a machine-soldered package, so you can't remove it. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array)) Besides, you can't generally purchase a CPU that would fit in that socket anyway (since, of course, who could install it?)

Comment: I have seen BGAs that are not soldered on and can be removed.  But I have only seen that in only a couple of desktop machines that were pretty old.

Comment: E-450 is about $40 shipped from China. And it would take more time to disassemble the system and assemble it back than for a person with experience and right equipment to replace the bga chip. In some countries I heard they still repair electronics.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know there were people good enough to hand-solder BGA. But I've never been to Brazil, you would know better than I...

Comment: It is doable at home if a person is willing to practice a bit. Take a look at http://www.instructables.com/id/BGA-rework/

Comment: Those instructions are for reflowing the solder, not outright replacing the chip

Comment: Tools required and preparation steps involved are the same. I just happen to like the video. I was able to swap south bridges on motherboards and GPUs on video cards using the same techniques - so I am talking from my own experience here.

Comment: Are you saying all you have to do is heat the thing up, pull the chip out, put the new one in and heat it again to set it? That's pretty cool, actually, I didn't know it was that easy.

Comment: I think for replacing BGA stuff, on your replacement parts you have to "re-ball" them.  It looks hard.  You'll need a stencil.  https://gregdavill.github.io/posts/dell-xps13-ram-upgrade/

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can, all you need is

- Solder wick,
- solder paste,
- soldering oven (i used an electric oven)
- a solder stencil,
- hot air gun,
- soldering iron,
- and some skill

If your upgrading you may need to flash your bios to a version that can see/use the new chip.  I can't guarantee that it will work, after all, I have only replaced an E300 with an E300. Look up ReBalling Cpu on youtube, its the same process.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading Android  emulator runs fine , lubuntu was pokey at least  the KDE was, dragging its feet. Theres loads more im going to try ,why not.Maybe CCTV who n knows  dont see why it needs binning yet. Anybody else used this dynamic disaster for re-purpose?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).